# Wordpress: Jquery .html function now executing inside PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

Actually I want to display a dynamic dropdown on selection of one dropdown.
Here is my html:

```
echo  '<select onchange="showcertificate(this.value);" value="'. $certificatelist .'" name=\'certificatelist\'>';
```

It is calling the function showcertficate, which is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showcertificate(vendorid)
  {
      var vendorid = vendorid;
      var xmlhttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.open("GET","admin-ajax.php?action=wpt_exam_certificatelist&u="+vendorid,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    <?php
      if(isset($_GET["u"]))
      {
     $vendorid = $_GET['u'];
      }
      $certquery = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID=wp_postmeta.post_id WHERE wp_posts.post_status='publish' AND wp_posts.post_type='certificate' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value='$vendorid'");
     foreach($certquery as $c)
        { ?>
    $("#cert").html('<option  name=\'certificatelist\'><?php echo $c->post_title; ?></option>');
      <?php }
      ?> 
  }
  </script>
```

The issue is that .html function is not executing inside foreach loop. If i remove foreach loop, it works fine.
I have already waste one day in it. Please help me.

Comment: are you attempting to use `PHP` client-side?

Comment: yes, because i have to display select dropdown once you select the value in upper dropdown.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax

Answer (score 0):

First, you draw wrong `option` it is not have attribute `name` it only have `value` attribute. Second $.html - rewrite whole inner html code, you are re-write for every each $().html - and you get only last change.

```
var options = '';
<?php foreach($certquery as $c) echo "options += '<option>{$c->post_title}</option>"; ?>
$("#cert").html(options);
```

Comment: The first issue you point out , yes i ust did mistake for just testing. Anyhow i tested it, it still not works. It is not the issue of getting last one only. It not displaying in anycase inside freach loop. aahhh don't know what's wrong

Comment: ANd yes one more issue, if you check by google chrome debugger and go in network, check the response it is adding "0" at end of code.

Comment: @NomanRizwan please show your output html, like see it how browser get it (source code of page)

Comment: <select onchange="showcertificate(this.value);" value="" name='certificatelist'>
<option value="11"> Vendor1 </option>
<option value="21"> Vendor2 </option>
<div id='certdiv'>
<select id='cert' name='certificatelist'></select>